# How to read NMEA data from the Holux M-1200 GPS receiver

Tags: linux, gpsd

I have a [Holux M-1200](http://www.holux.com/JCore/en/products/products_content.jsp?pno=227) GPS receiver and a `pl2303` data cable.

The cable appears as `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but when I turn on the receiver and `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` the device, only random symbold appear, like this:

```
➤ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 
E<�\E ��&��Q��]����Y��Ʉ�)W��E��$T_��/������^C
```

The only thing I could find was [this mailing list thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/6512).

How can I read valid data from the device?

Answer (score 4):

Use `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 38400` to **set the correct baud rate**.

Then you will get valid NMEA output with `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`:

```
$GPGGA,230859.000,5035.1348,N,00712.8746,E,1,8,1.37,97.7,M,47.8,M,,*62
$GPGSA,A,3,11,01,32,03,22,14,08,10,,,,,1.63,1.37,0.88*0C
$GPGSV,3,1,12,11,82,240,34,01,67,295,31,22,62,227,40,14,43,100,24*7D
$GPGSV,3,2,12,08,42,174,37,32,40,069,31,03,33,232,24,28,26,286,*7F
$GPGSV,3,3,12,10,15,058,28,17,12,319,,27,10,157,,24,02,010,*74
$GPRMC,230859.000,A,5035.1348,N,00712.8746,E,0.37,354.64,260417,,,A*6D
$GPVTG,354.64,T,,M,0.37,N,0.68,K,A*37
```